# How to extract internal JSON variables in php?

Tags: php, json

I am creating an API, but the end server that sends me back the information in JSON format that includes a RECORD attribute:

```
{
    "RECORD": [{
        "@ID": "1",
        "FULLNAME": "*\"* **** ****",
        "PHONE": "*******",
        "CELLULAR": "********",
        "LOGIN_STATUS": "*",
        "LOGIN_STATUS_TEXT": "****",
        "STUDENT_ACADEMIC_YEAR": "",
        "STUDENT_DEPARTMENT": "",
        "STUDENT_SPECIALITY": "",
        "STUDENT_PHONE": "",
        "STUDENT_CELLULARPHONE": "",
        "STUDENT_ADDRESS": " *",
        "STUDENT_EMAIL": "",
        "STUDENT_STATUS": "",
        "STUDENT_ID": "*",
        "TEACHER_ID": "*******",
        "CURRENTYEAR": "****",
        "TOKEN": "*************",
        "CURRENTFULLYEAR": "****"
    }]
}
```

How can I extract data from the inner attributes? I decoded with the following command:

```
$jsonRestData=json_decode($jsonRestData2, true);
```

I have tried:

```
$request_json["attributes"] = array( 
        "userid" => str_replace(" ","",$user_uid),
        "fullname" => $jsonRestData->FULLNAME,
        "email" => $jsonRestData->STUDENT_EMAIL,
        "role" => $jsonRestData->STUDENT_STATUS,
        "year" => $jsonRestData->STUDENT_ACADEMIC_YEAR,
        "department" => $jsonRestData->STUDENT_DEPARTMENT,
        "speciality" => $jsonRestData->STUDENT_SPECIALITY
    );
```

I also tried:

```
 $request_json["attributes"] = array( 
            "userid" => str_replace(" ","",$user_uid),
            "fullname" => $jsonRestData->RECORD->FULLNAME,
            "email" => $jsonRestData->RECORD->STUDENT_EMAIL,
            "role" => $jsonRestData->RECORD->STUDENT_STATUS,
            "year" => $jsonRestData->RECORD->STUDENT_ACADEMIC_YEAR,
            "department" => $jsonRestData->RECORD->STUDENT_DEPARTMENT,
            "speciality" => $jsonRestData->RECORD->STUDENT_SPECIALITY
        );
```

For the first example, I am getting an error:
Undefined property: stdClass::$FULLNAME

For the second I am getting an error:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: It `RECORD` has an array of records, so, something like this: `$jsonRestData->RECORD[0]->FULLNAME`.

Comment: Interesting @alx, unfortunately I am still getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Comment: That's weird, because I have tested my snippet, it works fine: https://repl.it/repls/SpanishDifferentSolaris

Comment: Thanks @alx! I found the issue. It seems that I didn't need to put "true" in the json_encode function. Once that was removed, I stopped getting the error messages!
You should put that comment in a reply with the example so I can mark it as the right answer :)

Comment: OK, will do, with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code (2nd part, one with `RECORD`) has only one problem: it was assuming `RECORD` is, well, a record. But apparently it was an array with single record in it.

As for the putting `true` in `json_decode`, with this much of context it does not really matter, because does not give clear benefits or disadvantages. But if you do use `true` there, you need to adjust the code accordingly because with `true` output is nested array, but without it output is nested objects and array.

Here is a sample PHP that shows both ways to do that -- with `true` and without it.

```php
<?php
$jsonRestData2 = '{
    "RECORD": [{
        "@ID": "1",
        "FULLNAME": "*\"* **** ****",
        "PHONE": "*******",
        "CELLULAR": "********",
        "LOGIN_STATUS": "*",
        "LOGIN_STATUS_TEXT": "****",
        "STUDENT_ACADEMIC_YEAR": "",
        "STUDENT_DEPARTMENT": "",
        "STUDENT_SPECIALITY": "",
        "STUDENT_PHONE": "",
        "STUDENT_CELLULARPHONE": "",
        "STUDENT_ADDRESS": " *",
        "STUDENT_EMAIL": "",
        "STUDENT_STATUS": "",
        "STUDENT_ID": "*",
        "TEACHER_ID": "*******",
        "CURRENTYEAR": "****",
        "TOKEN": "*************",
        "CURRENTFULLYEAR": "****"
    }]
}';

$jsonRestData = json_decode($jsonRestData2);

$request_json = [];
$request_json["attributes"] = array(
    "fullname"   => $jsonRestData->RECORD[0]->FULLNAME,
    "email"      => $jsonRestData->RECORD[0]->STUDENT_EMAIL,
    "role"       => $jsonRestData->RECORD[0]->STUDENT_STATUS,
    "year"       => $jsonRestData->RECORD[0]->STUDENT_ACADEMIC_YEAR,
    "department" => $jsonRestData->RECORD[0]->STUDENT_DEPARTMENT,
    "speciality" => $jsonRestData->RECORD[0]->STUDENT_SPECIALITY,
);

print_r($request_json);

$jsonRestData = json_decode($jsonRestData2, true);

$request_json = [];
$request_json["attributes"] = array(
    "fullname"   => $jsonRestData['RECORD'][0]['FULLNAME'],
    "email"      => $jsonRestData['RECORD'][0]['STUDENT_EMAIL'],
    "role"       => $jsonRestData['RECORD'][0]['STUDENT_STATUS'],
    "year"       => $jsonRestData['RECORD'][0]['STUDENT_ACADEMIC_YEAR'],
    "department" => $jsonRestData['RECORD'][0]['STUDENT_DEPARTMENT'],
    "speciality" => $jsonRestData['RECORD'][0]['STUDENT_SPECIALITY'],
);

print_r($request_json);
```

And here is what that sample code outputs:

```
Array
(
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => *"* **** ****
            [email] =>
            [role] =>
            [year] =>
            [department] =>
            [speciality] =>
        )

)
Array
(
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => *"* **** ****
            [email] =>
            [role] =>
            [year] =>
            [department] =>
            [speciality] =>
        )

)
```

As you can see, output is identical, i.e. both ways work fine.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE :**

The code works when " is iscaped, check this : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b1192db07cb3876a9c80e9ca25f88406117c0b5

The problem in your code is in the JSON string,  in full name you must fix the string inside. (fix closing string "")

```
$json_string='{
"RECORD": [{
    "@ID": "1",
    "FULLNAME": "*",
    "PHONE": "*******",
    "CELLULAR": "********",
    "LOGIN_STATUS": "*",
    "LOGIN_STATUS_TEXT": "****",
    "STUDENT_ACADEMIC_YEAR": "",
    "STUDENT_DEPARTMENT": "",
    "STUDENT_SPECIALITY": "",
    "STUDENT_PHONE": "",
    "STUDENT_CELLULARPHONE": "",
    "STUDENT_ADDRESS": " *",
    "STUDENT_EMAIL": "",
    "STUDENT_STATUS": "",
    "STUDENT_ID": "*",
    "TEACHER_ID": "*******",
    "CURRENTYEAR": "****",
    "TOKEN": "*************",
    "CURRENTFULLYEAR": "****"
}]
}';

$json_array=json_decode($json_string,true);
$records=$json_array['RECORD'][0];

//example of use
echo "FULL NAME : ".$records['FULLNAME'];
```

You can use this link to check or validate your JSON STRING : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Formatter says original JSON is valid. That quote character was properly escaped with backslash.

Comment: Normally it works, please try the escaped code and share the result !

Comment: That is a different issue, but the json data is correct. The reason the name has \" in the middle is because it starts with ד"ר, which is the Hebrew version of "dr." for doctors. It uses the \" so that the " won't close the object, as you suggested.
One of the commentators wrote the issue. It was the user of RECORD[0] mixed with removing true from the json_encode command.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @NimrodYanai , it works also with the escaped code, check this : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b1192db07cb3876a9c80e9ca25f88406117c0b5

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);`

After that, you can access your data as an array

Comment: Thank you. I will edit my original message - I showed the string, but I actually tried to extract the data after already decoding the json to an array:
$jsonRestData=json_decode($jsonRestData2, true);